# Enable wireless is not displayed on Lenovo ideapad z560

Tags: wireless

Very often i see wireless disconnect issues after upgrading to 16.02 
rfkill list all is not showing ideapad wlan.

please help me in fixing this issue permanently!!

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0510]
 Kernel modules: bcma, wl

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe -v wl`